# fatal: Unable to create '/home/circleci/project/.git/index.lock': File exists

Tags: git, circleci

I'm running a step in my workflow that performs `git checkout branchname` right after CircleCI's built in  `- checkout` step and I'm getting the following error: `fatal: Unable to create '/home/circleci/project/.git/index.lock': File exists.`

The branch `branchname` already exists. It gets created as part of this step process, all `yarn addFilesToCommit` does is run a build step that adds a couple of JSON files to a folder that gets tracked. If `branchname` doesn't exist the build goes through, only on subsequant runs does it fail with the error.

```
git checkout -b branchname | git checkout branchname
yarn addFilesToCommit
git add .
git commit -m "Sync"
git push --force --set-upstream origin branchname
```

I've tried doing `rm -rf /home/circleci/project/.git/index.lock` and `rm -rf /home/circleci/project/.git/index` like some other posts mention but with no luck.

If I run the build and `ssh` into it it seems to run the command with no problem. Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your first line with
`git checkout -b branchname && git checkout branchname`

pipes doesn't guarantee the sequential execution ([see here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37508/in-what-order-do-piped-commands-run)), that's why you're getting this error, basically, your `checkout` is called even before your `checkout -b` is finished